# Can a computer have two sets of "tweaks"?

Tags: unity, gnome, gnome-tweaks

My computer is running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and I've downloaded Gnome Tweaks and "tweaked" my desktop. Can I add any other tweaks, if so which/what? For example can I download Unity tweaks as well or will two different tweaks on the same computer create problems ? I would like to be able to be able to create links, colour directories and push directories closer to each other on the desktop.
Thanks Garoolgan

Comment: Didn't you [ask this same question yesterday](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1316323/ubuntu-20-04-and-gnome-tweaks-can-i-add-other-tweaks)? From what I can understand, you want to have a greater degree over the appearance of your desktop environment. If you're looking for fine-grain control over the look and feel of your GUI, I would suggest learning about Gnome Theme development.

Comment: What I would like to know is whether downloading a second set of Tweaks will create problems. The Gnome set will not allow me to colour directories on my desktop and elsewhere, it will not allow me to create links between files and it will not allow me to "push" directories on my desktop closer together as there is a "zone" around each directory, visible when you "hover" the mouse on it. I could do all these with Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: You can have several applications installed that can modify your system, yes. I have used Gnome Tweaks and dconf-editor together for quite some time without hassle and both can modify Gnome to accomplish certain goals — albeit different from the ones you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 20.04 and Gnome Tweaks. Can I add other Tweaks?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1316323/ubuntu-20-04-and-gnome-tweaks-can-i-add-other-tweaks)

Comment: Be specific on what you want to do. Your current question is too broad and not well defined for the format of this site.

Comment: Thanks to Matigo for his reply, and I can not understand why vanadium who obviously knows far more than myself insists that my question is "too broad" as I can't see another way of asking it.

Answer (score 0):

You can have as many tweak apps (GNOME tweaks, unity tweaks) as you want and they will not conflict because GNOME Tweaks, for example, is only tweaking GNOME while you are using GNOME. Unity Tweaks have nothing to do with GNOME tweaks, so you should be fine.